# How do I set up a wireless printer on Windows 8 without a wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, ad-hoc-network

So we just got a new computer (old hard drive bit the dust) with Windows 8 and at the same time decided to upgrade to a wireless printer.  I've read that you can't set up an ad hoc wireless network on Windows 8, so can I still set up the printer to be used wireless somehow?  It's for my husband's small business, and there is no need to add a wireless router to the system, especially not for the sole purpose of removing a single cable running across the desk, but he was happy about getting the wireless printer, so I was hoping for some sort of workaround.  Thank you!

Comment: are you saying you ***do not*** have a wireless network at home?

Comment: Try the steps here: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-set-up-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/ try the first steps at least to see if your Windows 8 wireless supports the hosted network capability...

Answer (score 1):

Configure your (or spare one) smartphone as a portable mobile hotspot. Then set-up your printer and computer to use its SSID. In this way you don't need to have any wireless router in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect your printer to your network first, as it won't connect directly to the computer itself (ad hoc).

This can likely be done by using the controls on the printer to connect to your wireless access point/router. This is much the same as connecting any other computer to a wireless network.

Scan for networks, select yours, enter the password. If you printer doesn't have a screen, you may have to plug it in via USB for this step, and unplug it later.

Once the printer is on the network, get on the computer and go to:

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Printers. Click "Add printer". Choose network printer. It should be straightforward from there.

Microsoft has a basic tutorial here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-or-remove-a-printer